# I can't login into account after update ps_customer table in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: sql, prestashop

Good morning,

I need to update some customer information like optin or newsletter. Change values from 0 to 1 or vice versa. I do it by this SQL update and this is works:

```
Db::getInstance()->update(
        'customer',
        array('optin' => '1'),
        'id_customer = ' . $this->context->customer->id
    );
```

After this operation the customer cant login to his account by old password. When I change password in back office, everything is good. Where is the problem ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It has no sense :)

Comment: What do U mean ?